# How to get screen width, and pass from JS to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

What I want to do is, display dynamic content via pure javascript based on screen size.

HTML

```
<script>
   var width=screen.width;
</script>
<script src="/js.php"></script>
```

js.php

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/javascript;charset=UTF-8"); // Content Type

    $width=$_GET['width'];

    if($width>480){
?>
       document.writeln('<div style="width:100%;background-color:red;">LARGE SCREEN, GO WILD!</div>');
<?php
    }else{
?>
       document.writeln('<div style="width:100%;background-color:blue;">ITS A MOBILE, BE CONSERVATIVE!</div>');
<?php
    }
?>
```

The wrong point is at the line with $_GET, but I don't know how to get it right, please help. Thanks!

Comment: `/js.php?width=some_width`, but this is not going to work. Your server delivers the file as PHP, and the browsers refuses to load PHP into script tag.

Comment: This would be way easier to do with a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)... you're sure that won't work?

Comment: @HewwoCraziness that will definitely work, but will be a problem in my case since I track views/clicks/ctr of each dynamic content piece. Media query will just add up views that will never be clicked. Sorry I didn't state this in my original post.